# XML parse element inside element

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

XML file:

```
<one>
     <two>
          <three>
              <text>HELLO</text>
          </three>
          <text>HI</text>
     </two>
     <text>OLA</text>
</one>
```

I need to parse the file and printout only element text which is inside element one, two, and three. So the printout for this file would be only "HELLO" and not "HELLO HI OLA".

My code:

```
        XDocument _doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");

        var time = _doc.XPathSelectElements("/one/two/three/text");

        foreach (var element in time)
        {

            Label1.Text +=element.Value;
        }
```

Comment: The only element selected by your XPath would have the string value that you seek: `"HELLO"`.   What's the problem?

Comment: Error: "System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: 'Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function."

Comment: The example xml you posted will work fine. Does your original xml have namespaces?